# iOS navigator longitude/latitude with google maps V3

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I'm using Phonegap for developing a mobile app and when I receive the native iOS navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() longitude/latitude for Copenhagen, it differs a lot from the one I need to add to google maps api

iOS navigator gives me
Longitude: 122.406417
Latitude: 37.785834

While Google Maps api gives me
Longitude: 12.577972
Latitude: 55.668473

Is there a way to convert them og am I missing a setting?

Thanks
Kasper

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOs, but the coordinates should be returned for the same geographic reference sytem as defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#coordinates_interface . It guess that the coordinates are not for another geographic system, they are simply incorrect.